# Crystal report New line after detect 3 commas

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal report a New line after detecting 3 commas
I have Text like "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
how could I code?

I would like to show

A,B,C,

D,E,F,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
local numbervar counter := 0;
local stringvar result := "";
local numbervar i;
For i := 1 to Len({@yourText}) do
(
IF {@yourText}[i] <> "," Then result := result + {@yourText}[i];

IF {@yourText}[i] = "," Then 
   IF counter = 2 THEN 
   (counter := 0; 
    result := result + CHR(10) + CHR(13);)
   ELSE 
    (counter := counter + 1; 
     result := result + {@yourText}[i];) ;
);

result;
```

[image]